# Material-Ui theme customization: hover on contained button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm trying to configure a theme for Material-Ui on my React app. In the app I use two different type of buttons, contained and outlined. The problem is the hover effect on the contained button (the outlined works fine) and will default to a grey hover effect.

```
overrides: {
 MuiButton: {
  contained: {
   backgroundColor: palette.primary.main,
   color: palette.primary.contrastText,
   "&:hover": {
     backgroundColor: palette.primary.active,
   },
  },
  outlined: {
    color: palette.primary.main,
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: palette.primary.active,
    },
  },
 }
}
```

outlined = working
contained = not working

This is from the element inspector, where my color is the one with a strike through 
**background-color:**
#e0e0e0.MuiButton-contained:hover
<strike>rgba(23, 0, 255, 0.3).MuiButton-contained:hover</strike>

Anyone got any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You can try adding `root`, so something like:

```
overrides: {
 MuiButton: {
  root: {
   "&:hover": {
     backgroundColor: palette.primary.active,
   },
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work, but I mangae to solve it with an important flag.
`"&:hover": {
  backgroundColor: '${palette.primary.active} !important',
},`

Comment: Hm, well good! Maybe it was in a conflict with `MuiButtonBase`?

Comment: In v5, the object needs to be wrapped with `styleOverrides` https://next.material-ui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides

Answer (score 5):

By default, the hover color (the background, for contained; the border, for outlined) will be `palette.primary.dark`. It could be these conflicting setup might cause some issues, try setting it there.